# Убрать экранирование и юникод

Tags: php, json, symfony, unicode, экранирование

Есть вот такой код :

```
$this->encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
$this->normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
$this->serializer = new Serializer($this->normalizers, $this->encoders);    
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->where('p.appleStoreId = :keyword AND p.dateAddRecord BETWEEN :start AND :end')
                ->setParameter('keyword', $this->keyword)
                ->setParameter('start', (new \DateTimeImmutable('now'))->sub(new \DateInterval("P6D")))
                ->setParameter('end', new \DateTimeImmutable('now'))
                ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
                ->getQuery();
$this->serializer->serialize($query->getResult(), 'json'));
```

На выходе получаю:

> \ / \ /site.com\ /ru\ /app\ /

> in this\u00a0tay\u00a0p\u00a0adventure\u00a0to

Данные в БД храняться в utf8 и на сайте кодировка utf-8 прописана. Были идеи на счет `json_encoding`, но там только 1 параметр принимается.

Answer (score 0):

Надо изменить ваш $this->encoders на

```
$this->encoders = [new JsonEncoder(new JsonEncode(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))];
```